# Error Webservice al Subir factura a la DIAN

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Buen día.

Estoy tratando de subir al webservice de la DIAN (entidad tributaria en Colombia) una factura, con anterioridad había creado una publicación para la parte de la "autentificacion WSS" la cual quedo solucionada, pero ahora el problema es que el webservice de la DIAN me tira el error de: **Error [null] inesperado al procesar la solicitud WS entrante**.

Ya he investigado con la misma DIAN pero jamas responden, si alguien ya visto el tema y este conectando al servicio le agradecería su respuesta, les dejo el Request y Response:

El Request enviado es:

```
POST /habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co
Accept: */*
User-Agent: moneyBox
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 28198
Expect: 100-continue
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
    <soapenv:header>
        <wsse:security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:usernametoken wsu:id="UsernameToken-2">
                <wsse:username>d8xxxxxx-exxx-4xxx-axxx-aaxxxxxxxxxa</wsse:username>
                <wsse:password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText">e098cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4501b5</wsse:password>
                <wsse:nonce encodingtype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">bW9xxxxxxxxxDcwNA==</wsse:nonce>
                <wsu:created>2019-02-13T12:25:04.000Z</wsu:created>
            </wsse:usernametoken>
        </wsse:security>
    </soapenv:header>
    <soapenv:body>
        <rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
            <rep:nit>700xxxxxx</rep:nit>
            <rep:invoicenumber>980000000</rep:invoicenumber>
            <rep:issuedate>2019-02-13T12:25:04</rep:issuedate>
            <rep:document>UEs...El_Zip_en_Base64....uMjcwNw==</rep:document>
        </rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
    </soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>
```

Y el response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 13 Feb 2019 17:25:08 GMT
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: Multipart/Related; start-info="text/xml"; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="----=_Part_356292_546049942.1550078708580"
Set-Cookie: TS0133d910=01ca0e1ef651253b25b49afd1557f600dec2280bb5852510eeffa34063be7fa62f74d86b09c95f04d731f25eb78b11362ff2483058; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
------=_Part_356292_546049942.1550078708580
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:header>
        <wsse:security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap-env:mustunderstand="1">
        ..... muchas etiquetas del Firmado Digital... (Signature)
        </wsse:security>
    </soap-env:header>
    <soap-env:body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:id="id-352783">
        <ns2:enviofacturaelectronicarespuesta xmlns:ns2="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura" xmlns:ns3="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ConsultaDocumentos" xmlns:ns4="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/VersionDespliegue">
            <ns2:version>Componente DIAN</ns2:version>
            <ns2:receiveddatetime>2019-02-13T12:25:06.924-05:00</ns2:receiveddatetime>
            <ns2:responsedatetime>2019-02-13T12:25:08.567-05:00</ns2:responsedatetime>
            <ns2:response>100</ns2:response>
            <ns2:comments>Error [null] inesperado al procesar la solicitud WS entrante..</ns2:comments>
        </ns2:enviofacturaelectronicarespuesta>
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
------=_Part_356292_546049942.1550078708580--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado, el problema no era la forma en que enviaba los datos, sino que la entidad Tributaria DIAN internamente no tenia detectado el problema, por lo cual después de estar mas de 2 semanas insistiendo e insistiendo en que verificaran el error, al fin dieron la solución y corrección en su webservice, pero los descarados no tuvieron **hasta ahorita** la decencia de responder los correos ni la queja en el PQRS, solamente solucionaron la recepción y listo.

**Otro punto importante** es que los anexos técnicos no están al 100% bien, los ejemplos tienen erratas muy importantes que los sigues al paso de la letra no harás nunca el envío de los datos, por ejemplo:

1) El **boundary** en los anexos técnicos esta mal indicado y utilizado, aqui te digo como lo resolvi: [Como usar MTOM con SOAP para adjuntar archivos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239244/como-usar-mtom-con-soap-para-adjuntar-archivos/239859)

2) No se indica que para usar el **boundary** debes establecer la cabecera el los "Headers" del socket, y no como parte del cuerpo del mensaje.

3) En los anexos tecnicos se menciona un conjunto de "cabeceras" para el XML de Factura Electronica, que es casi **diferente** a las cabeceras de los XML de Ejemplo que ofrece la DIAN. Entonces cuales son los correctos? (aun sigo trasteando esto).

4) En el 2019 cambiaron la version del UBL a utilizar, por lo cual ahora requieren otras etiquetas adicionales que NO se mencionan en ningun anexo tecnico y lo publicaron apenas ayer **20 de Fabrero 2019** dentro del "Kit de Herramientas**.

5) Los ejemplos XML del **Kit de Herramientas** no estan bien verificados, existen erratas en las cabeceras y continua persistiendo esta estandarizacion sobre CUALES cabeceras usas en el XML.

6) Cambiaron de **fe:Invoice** a **Invoice** pero NO lo mencionan en ningun Anexo, solo lo ponen en sus ejemplos XML, esto afecta a la hora de que su Webservice inspecciona los elementos (acceso a los nodos).

Si alguien tiene mas para aportar se agradeceria porque la DIAN es completamente irresponsable en este "Programa de Facturacion Electronica", no atienden los telefonos ni los correos, muchos menos mis quejas en PQRS... me quedo en visto :P