# Como usar MTOM con SOAP para adjuntar archivos?

Tags: php, webservice, api, soap

Estoy conectandome a un servicio WSLD SOAP donde es necesario usar MTOM para enviar información adjunta, estoy intentando subir un archivo ZIP en base64 pero el servidor me retorna el error de que no encuentra la información del mensaje, osea del adjunto, a continuación les indico lo que envío al servidor usando **cURL en PHP** para ver si alguien puede orientarme en que estoy mandando mal que no permite al servidor leer el documento adjunto.

> **Mensaje de Error:** Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to internalize
>   message; nested exception is
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize
>   message

```
POST /ruta/portal.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: empresa.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PHP-7
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="------=_Part_1_363f118.a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303"
Content-Length: 28908
Expect: 100-continue

------=_Part_1_363f118.a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.empresa.com/ruta/EnvioDocumentos">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:id="UsernameToken-2">
                <wsse:Username>xxxxxxxxx</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText">xxxxx</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce encodingtype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">zzzzzzzzzz</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2019-02-19T16:07:47.000Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <rep:EnvioDocumento>
            <rep:Document><inc:Include href="cid:363f118a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e96633032" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></rep:Document>
        </rep:EnvioDocumento>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


------=_Part_1_363f118.a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303
Content-Type: application/zip; name="archivo_003a699d00.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <363f118a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e96633032>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="archivo_003a699d00.zip" filename="archivo_003a699d00.zip"

UEsD....Datos_en_Base64.....zA3
------=_Part_1_363f118.a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, mi error estaba en la forma de uso el **boundary** dato interesante y que hace una gran diferiencia es que cuando uses adjuntos y las partes se esten accediendo por etiquetas boundary deberas declarara la etiqueta con "X" nombre y despues al momento de declararla en el cuerpo del mensaje deberas **nombrar la etiqueta** pero anteponerle dos guines (--).

El boundary mencionado en la cabecera debe ser **----=_Part_1** (cuatro guiones) y en el cuerpo del mensaje debe ir **------=_Part_1** (dos guiones extra).

Ejemplo corregido:

```
POST /ruta/portal.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: empresa.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PHP-7
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="----=_Part_1_363f118.a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303"
Content-Length: 28908
Expect: 100-continue

------=_Part_1_363f118.a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.empresa.com/ruta/EnvioDocumentos">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:id="UsernameToken-2">
                <wsse:Username>xxxxxxxxx</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText">xxxxx</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce encodingtype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">zzzzzzzzzz</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2019-02-19T16:07:47.000Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <rep:EnvioDocumento>
            <rep:Document><inc:Include href="cid:363f118a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e96633032" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></rep:Document>
        </rep:EnvioDocumento>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

------=_Part_1_363f118.a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303
Content-Type: application/zip; name="archivo_003a699d00.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <363f118a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e96633032>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="archivo_003a699d00.zip" filename="archivo_003a699d00.zip"

UEsD....Datos_en_Base64.....zA3
------=_Part_1_363f118.a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303--
```

> **IMPORTANTE:** puedes usar un boundary de solo "hash" y al mencionarlo en
>   el cuerpo quedaría mas entendible.

Ejemplo:

```
POST /ruta/portal.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: empresa.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PHP-7
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303"
Content-Length: 28908
Expect: 100-continue

--a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.empresa.com/ruta/EnvioDocumentos">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:id="UsernameToken-2">
                <wsse:Username>xxxxxxxxx</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText">xxxxx</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce encodingtype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">zzzzzzzzzz</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2019-02-19T16:07:47.000Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <rep:EnvioDocumento>
            <rep:Document><inc:Include href="cid:363f118a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e96633032" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></rep:Document>
        </rep:EnvioDocumento>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


--a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303
Content-Type: application/zip; name="archivo_003a699d00.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <363f118a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e96633032>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="archivo_003a699d00.zip" filename="archivo_003a699d00.zip"

UEsD....Datos_en_Base64.....zA3
--a4e1f4f9730a01986d6c6fb8e9663303--
```